# increase css animation rotate duration with jquery and input range

Tags: jquery, css, animation, rotation, duration

I use `-webkit-animation` properties to rotate an element, but I want to control that duration using jQuery and input range.

However, it does not work, can't seem to figure out why.

```
$('#speed').change(function() {
    $('.rotate').css({'-webkit-animation': 'rotation '+this.value+'s linear infinite'});
});
```

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/BZLGE/1/)

Answer (score 1):

you need to use requestAnimationFrame approach it is much easier to control than adding and removing animation key frames which is not hard but what is harder is to modify those css animations and or create new ones.

whereas, this js function requestAnimationFrame is like setTimeInterval but it only calls when  screen can render it so it doesn't unnecessarily waste cpu.

**http://jsfiddle.net/BZLGE/10/** <<

```
var spd=0, r=0, box = $('.rotate');

$('#speed').on('change', function () {
    spd = +(this.value);
});

function start() {
    r += spd;
    box.css('transform', 'rotate(' + r + 'deg)');
    requestAnimationFrame(start);
}
start();
```

Comment: + sign before (this.value) is a shortcut in js to convert string value  to number easily.

Answer (score 0):

Strange, but you could recreate .rotate on change, which will restart the animation with the new speed.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BZLGE/7/)

```
$('#speed').on('change', function () {

    var element = $(".rotate"),
    n = element.clone(true);

    element.before(n);

    $(".rotate:last").remove();
    $('.rotate').css("-webkit-animation", "rotate " + (30/this.value) + "s linear infinite");
});
```